# Windows tracerpt generates invalid event schema

Tags: windows, windows-10, event-log

I'm using the Windows Performance Recorder from the [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/) to record event trace logs.

Event trace logs are not self-describing, and rely on "providers" registered with Windows in order to correctly parse the binary event details. Data collection will be happening on one machine and analysis on another, so the provider information needs to be exported from the machine generating the event trace log.

The [`tracerpt`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tracerpt_1) tool generates an Event Schema and bundles up related data with its `-export` option, which seems like everything I need.

**The problem**

When I use the generated Event Schema with `tracefmt` to generate parseable text, it prints a warning:

> `WARNING: TdhLoadManifest("traces/providers.man") returned error code 1465`

and the generated `FmtFile.txt` has lots of entries that were not able to be decoded. These show up with "Unknown" in the event prefix, like:

> `Unknown(0v0o34t0): GUID=9b79ee91-b5fd-41c0-a243-4248e266e9d0 (decoding error 1168)`

I did some research and found that the [Message Compiler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/message-compiler--mc-exe-) can provide more detailed errors for Event Schema files. Running it on the same file shows:

> `traces/providers.man : error : Duplicate opcode value 35(0x23) used in opcode : 'opcode13'.`

This looks like a correct statement, as shown by

```
[XML]$xml = Get-Content .\traces\providers.man
echo (Select-XML -Xml $xml -XPath '//n:provider[.//n:opcode[@value="35"]/following-sibling::n:opcode[@value="35"]]' -Namespace @{ "n" = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events"}).Node
```

which returns

```
name             : Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntimeRundown
symbol           : provider1
guid             : {a669021c-c450-4609-a035-5af59af4df18}
source           : Xml
messageFileName  : noMessageFile
resourceFileName : noResourceFile
events           : events
keywords         : keywords
tasks            : tasks
opcodes          : opcodes
templates        : templates
maps             : maps
```

But that's weird because this seems like a normal built-in/Microsoft-provided provider, so I assume I'm doing something wrong to generate the Event Schema. If I edit the Event Schema to fix this issue there are several others that `tracefmt` and `mc` complain about.

**My question**

Why is the generated event schema invalid and how do I fix the underlying cause? I can manually "fix" this Event Schema and script the changes, but that's annoying and with no guarantee it won't break in a slightly different way later.

**To reproduce**

The issue can be reproduced from a clean VM available [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines) by running this in PowerShell:

```
# Setup Windows Performance Toolkit
Invoke-WebRequest `
  -Uri https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2026036 `
  -OutFile adksetup.exe

./adksetup.exe /features OptionId.WindowsPerformanceToolkit `
  /log adk-setup.log `
  /ceip off `
  /installpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\"

# Wait for setup to complete
sleep 10

# Generate dummy traces
mkdir traces
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe' `
  -start GeneralProfile.verbose `
  -start CPU.verbose
sleep 10
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe' `
  -stop traces/wpr-result.etl

# Generate Event Schema
tracerpt -l traces/wpr-result.etl -export traces/providers.man

# Confirm with tracefmt that the generated Event Schema is not valid
$tracefmt = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\*\x64\tracefmt.exe" | `
  Sort CreationTime -Desc | Select -First 1

& $tracefmt.FullName traces/wpr-result.etl -man traces/providers.man

# Confirm with Message Compiler that the generated Event Schema is not valid
$mc = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\*\x64\mc.exe" | `
  Sort CreationTime -Desc | Select -First 1
& $mc.FullName traces/providers.man
```